# NULL value shown on filter regardless

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a calculated field to only show week numbers for the latest four weeks from today. I called it *latest_4_weeks* with the following definition:

```
if (([week_number] <= datepart('week',today())) and ([week_number] > datepart('week',today()) -4)) then [week_number]
end
```

When I add this field to my columns an unwanted `NULL` value shows up. I still haven't been able to tell the Tableau to ignore all the null values using `IFNULL()`, etc.

And when I manually filter out the `NULL` value, the filter no longer works as it should. Since it will now apply the current values and all other values that relate to next week will be ignored.

[image]

How can I effectively remove `NULL` in my calculated field?

Comment: You can just check NULL and **Exclude** only that in the same filter box so all new values will also be retained.

Comment: So there is no way to write in the calculated field to ignore the null values @JilJungJuk?

Comment: If I understand what you are after from a visual perspective I believe an else block with a value of '' will do the trick. This will create a blank value rather than a null and will therefore appear empty on your view.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the **NULL's** are being created is because your don't have a **else block** that assigns value when the condition is not Satisfied. So add a else block

```
e.g IF(COND) THEN A ELSE B END.
```

Or. You can also exclude NULL if you dont want to assign an else block in the same filter block by checking the Exclude option on bottom right corner.

Comment: But I don't want an `ELSE` block because I show the week number regardless of the condition. How can you tell an else block not to show anything if a value is `NULL`?

Comment: I guess what you are saying here (regardless of cond) and the code you tried are contradictory. Guess you have a cond that shows week numbers only for the last 4 weeks and for others its not showing the week-numbers rather a NULL. Do you want to filter out last 4 weeks data ? I can help you in another fashion.

Comment: @Disasterkid I don't understand this part of your comment "I show the week number regardless of the condition". According to the formula, you only show the week number in a limited number of circumstances (i.e. the last 4 weeks). Can you clarify what you mean?